# Trying to replace newline characters in a csv with commas using python

Tags: python, csv, newline

I have a jotform form that I export into a csv file.  I am using an unordered list in the form so the responders can rank school shops in order of interest.  The CSV file looks like the following in notepad:

```
"Submission Date","First Name","Last Name",Email,"Student ID","Orderable List"
"Aug 2, 2022",Cyndi,Bussey,cbussey@fcts.us,12345,"1: Programming and web
2: Animal Science
3: Landscape
4: Health Tech
5: Culinary
6: Carpentry
7: Electrical
8: Advanced Manufacturing
9: Auto body
10: Auto Tech
11: Cosmo
12: Welding
13: one more
14: two more"
```

I need the row to look like:
"Aug 2, 2022",Cyndi,Bussey,cbussey@fcts.us,12345,"1: Programming and web","2: Animal Science","3: Landscape","4: Health Tech","5: Culinary","6: Carpentry","7: Electrical","8: Advanced Manufacturing","9: Auto body","10: Auto Tech","11: Cosmo","12: Welding","13: one more","14: two more" (newline for end of row)

I need each shop to be in a separate column for each responder, not in separate rows, which is what is happening now. There are apparently newline characters at the end of every shop.  I want to replace the newline with a comma.  How would I do this in python?

Note:  I am not real versed on lambda....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using the `csv` module, they need to be in separate list elements in the row that you write to the file. So you should use `data.splitlines()` to turn it into a list of lines, and add that to the end of the other columns. The `csv` module puts the comma delimiters between them.

Comment: What do you want the new output columns to look like? **Add as update to question**

Comment: "Aug 2, 2022",Cyndi,Bussey,cbussey@fcts.us,12345,"1: Programming and web","2: Animal Science","3: Landscape","4: Health Tech","5: Culinary","6: Carpentry","7: Electrical","8: Advanced Manufacturing","9: Auto body","10: Auto Tech","11: Cosmo","12: Welding","13: one more","14: two more" (newline for end of row)

Comment: Barmar, yes, but this is what jotform gives me, and there will be about 160 students, so I would rather not fix by hand!

Comment: Id also like to get rid of the #: at the beginning of each shop

Comment: I am currently reading the file by using f = open("file.csv", r)  and then Lines = f.readlines() and for line in LInes:

Comment: 1) Attention to detail is important to these sort of problems and the fact that you ignored **Add as update to question** does not bode well. 2) This `"1: Programming and web","2: Animal Science", ...` is not going to work as I am sure the students will not have the same ranking to their choices. You will need to come up generic columns, say `"choice_1", "choice_2", "choice_3", ...`

Answer (score 1):

Although it's a bit unclear what you're really asking for, I'll err on the side of answering the question in your title over any other interpretations of the rest of your question.

Use a proper csv reader and writer to handle formatting. It'll save you a lot of trouble.

```py
import csv


def transform(row):
    date, fname, lname, email, sid, ordlist = row
    return date, fname, lname, email, sid, ordlist.replace('\n', ',')


with open('file.csv', newline='') as file, open('transformed.csv', 'w') as newfile:
    rows = csv.reader(file)
    csv.writer(newfile).writerows(map(transform, rows))
```

You'll get:

```
Submission Date,First Name,Last Name,Email,Student ID,Orderable List
"Aug 2, 2022",Cyndi,Bussey,cbussey@fcts.us,12345,"1: Programming and web,2: Animal Science,3: Landscape,4: Health Tech,5: Culinary,6: Carpentry,7: Electrical,8: Advanced Manufacturing,9: Auto body,10: Auto Tech,11: Cosmo,12: Welding,13: one more,14: two more"
```

Note this quick script also replaces newlines in the 6th header, but since there aren't any, it has no effect.